# Constructing a neural network

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am a beginner in neural networks and am trying to follow a research paper where I have to construct a neural network. This is the structure of the neural network.

[image: neural network structure]

This structure is used to build two separate CNN, the first takes an image scaled to `32*640` as input, and the second takes three images scaled to `32*640` as input.

So far, I have written this code (for the CNN that takes a single image as input)

But I think that this doesn't seem right. Can someone help me in building its CNN?

```
single = Sequential([
    Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 640, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='softmax'),
    Dense(4)
])

single.summary()
```

[image: input for 2 CNNs]

(a) is the input of first CNN and (b) is the input for second CNN. (each rectangle is an image)

Comment: are you sure it is 3 images? Or one image with 3 color channels (eg RGB) ?

Comment: No I am sure that it is 3 images

Comment: Your first `Dense` layer should have `activation='relu'` and the second one should have `activation='softmax'`. Everything else looks fine

Comment: But then how can I give the second type of input (3 images) to the neural network?